# Mostrar Resultados en Formato JSON con MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Quizás ya se ha visto o resuelto en algún otro tema manejado, pero igual en mi código tenga el error, mi pregunta es por que al usar `print_r($array_data);` si me muestra el array en el navegador y cuando lo paso a echo `json_encode($array_data);` ya no me lo muestra me esta faltando algo?

```
<?php
    include_once'conexion.php';

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Fallo la conexon a la base de datos";
    }
    else{

        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_servicio, ser_titulo,   ser_source_principal FROM imagenes");
        $array_data=array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)>0)
        {
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
                $array_data[]=$data;
            }   
        /*print_r($array_data);*/
        echo json_encode($array_data);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Cuando haces `print_r($array_data);` que te muestra?

Comment: esto es lo que me muestra si trae los registros de la base de datos lo extraño es que al pasarlo ajson no me lo muestra ni en log:Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_servicio] => 1 [ser_titulo] => laboratorio de an�lisis clinicos [ser_source_principal] => principal-paquete_integral_masculino20180815100033.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [id_servicio] => 2 [ser_titulo] => principal-rayos [ser_source_principal] => principal-rayos_x20180815105941 ) )

Comment: Que tal aquí de nueva cuenta, revisando exhaustivamente, me di cuenta que todo esta bien, lo que hace que no se vea en el navegador los valores obtenidos de php y pasados a json es que en la base de datos si tienes textos con tildes no los muestra, deben de ir los textos sin esa propiedad o a menos de que uses alguna función para que los acepte que si debe de haber de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de la versión 5.4.0 PHP en su función `json_encode` incluye la opción `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.

En tu caso puedes intentar esto:

```
echo json_encode($array_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

aun no puedo agregar comentarios, por eso contesto por aquí,
Puedes poner tu código javascript o jquery, probablemente este algo en esa parte.

Revisa dataType: "json", o ver la manera de agregar mensajes de error para revisarlo mas a fondo